# ANSYS APDL: Why writing using *vwrite for numbers with exp (10e12) resulting in asterisk?

Tags: ansys

I was trying to write to a file of two variable, one is integer, another is numbers with exponential, but the second one output as ************. I'm not sure why:

```
VAR1=10
VAR2=10e12

*CFOPEN, 'test.txt'
*VWRITE, VAR1, VAR2
%d; %f
*cfclose
```

my output is:

```
10; ****************
```

Any idea why? How do I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem was the float "f" and the "d" operator. If I use a double precision "G" and "I" operator I get the desired result:

```
VAR1=10
VAR2=10e12
*CFOPEN, 'test.txt'
*VWRITE,VAR1,VAR2
%I;%G
*VWRITE,VAR1,VAR2
%D;%F
*CFCLOSE
```

Output:

```
10;1.E+13
10;****************
```

Answer (score 0):

Check the MAPDL help on the *msg command; it has more examples of format descriptors.  The one you are looking for is %E and not %F.
Mike